# In a production planning model Or-tools, how to associate my production with orders?

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

The main goal of my CP-SAT model is to optimize the profitability of a production schedule (over 1 month) based on orders.

In the last part of my model, I must therefore check/control whether the volumes produced allow the remaining orders to be completed and within what time frame; I also know in advance that I must allow delays otherwise the model will not be resolvable, so I imagine that I cannot use cumulative constraints in this case.

To summarize I have a list of my productions:

```
list_productions =
[[Product 0,30,1], #[ProductNr(0,4),Quantity(1,200],Dayprod(1,20)] <= 3 intvar Ortools
[Product 1,100,1],
[Product 1,90,2],
[Product 2,40,2],
[Product 0,60,3],
[Product 2,40,3],
[Product 2,35,3],
[Product 3,35,3],
[Product 1,20,3],
[Product 3,5,3]]
```

And a orders list :

```
orders_list = [ 
[Product 1, 1, 25], #[ProductNr, DueDate, Volume] <= not variables, known values
[Product 1, 2, 50],
[Product 2, 1, 50],
[Product 2, 3, 35],
[Product 2, 2, 25],
[Product 3, 1, 10],
[Product 3, 2, 55],
[Product 3, 3, 30]]
```

And I have to know which orders will be delivered on time and which will not; or even better; for each production check if it will be attributed to an order delivered on time or to an order delivered late.
Of course, if an order is made up of 3 productions, it will be the production with the maximum DueDate which will define the delivery of this entire order.

Then I could quite easily impose, for example, penalties in the sales prices for late shipments.

Thanks in advance :),